# How to handle bulk records in httpput rest api?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am working on a rest api to re parent the account records from external system.
but when doing a put call with workbench, i am getting below error:

message: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of Map at [line:2, column:20]

errorCode: JSON_PARSER_ERROR

Could some please help.

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping = '/updateAccount/*')
 global with sharing class updateAccount {
 @HTTPPut
 global static List<Account> updateAcc(Map<String,String> accountMap) {
    RestRequest advRequest = RestContext.request;
    String advRequestURI = advRequest.requestURI;
    List<Account> accList;
    List<Account> accListUpdate;
    try {
        for(Account adv : [select id,parent from Account where id in :accountMap.keySet()]){
            accList.add(adv);
        }
        if(accList.size()>0){
            for(Account accUpdate : accList){
                accUpdate.parent = accountMap.get(accUpdate.id);
                accListUpdate.add(accUpdate);
            }               
        }
        update accListUpdate;
        return accListUpdate;
    } catch (System.Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Parent` should be `ParentId` in your code.

```
accUpdate.parentid = accountMap.get(accUpdate.id);
```

As far as the payload, when using the automatic JSON parser, you must wrap the entire thing in a "request". Also, you might be trying to pass in a List of some sort (`[...]`), but you are using a Map, so you need `{...}`. A proper request would look like:

```
{ "request": { "001...": "001...", "001...": "001..." } }
```

Side note:

```
if(accList.size()>0){
```

Is not necessary; it is logically acceptable to loop over an empty list.

Side note 2:

```
accListUpdate.add(accUpdate);
```

Is not necessary; you can directly update the records using the original list.

```
update accList;
```

Comment: i updated these changes and passing the json like below and seeing the same error. can you please have a look.

{ "request": { "001*******": "001********"} }

error: Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: request at [line:1, column:15